# Android placing imageView through Code

Tags: android, imageview

I want on the initialization of my activity in android to set the position of some imageView's 
by code.

Lets say I have five cards displayed on the screen, all placed in (0,0) by me in the XML.

I want to calculate the screen size (easy to do) and then place the first card at 0.2height , 0.2 width the second one 0.4height, 0.4 width, ETC.

I want to do it through code so i could change some constants in the future and the rest of the changes will apply automatically

Thanks.

Comment: You question is way too ambiguous.  Describe in more detail how your activity is set up, provide your XML and initialisation java code as well the relevant drawings/screenshots if applicable an explain exactly what (and preferably why) you want to do with your imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Create a LinearLayout container view in your layout, and then use code to add your new View to it

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

And then:

```
    ((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.container)).addView(myImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use "findViewById()" to inflate some parental layouts,
"new ImageView()" to construct new Views and ".add(myImageView)" to add them.
In your code u can use all kinds of setters for the imageview...

(btw: more details would be great, the question is kinda ambiguous)

Comment: I added some more info, Thanks!